# Two rails apps with the same database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, api, heroku

Is there any risks/cons with building two different applications that use the same database? Specifically two rails applications.

Why do I want this?
I have an REST API (built in rails) to power a mobile app and I also need a web application for administering the database. Due to the security issues with using token based authentication on a web app it seems like a better idea using sessions for the web app.

Comment: Why do you want split app? In my opinion, it is better split just controller.

Comment: Having an admin app is actually a good pattern IMO

Comment: I don't have any direct experience of this, but the two big things to consider will be data integrity and database connectivity. Some DB's won't allow you to connect to multiple clients at once. I can write an answer but I don't have any hard facts

Comment: @RichPeck Any facts I can provide to help you elaborate?

Comment: Not really, I have similar aspirations and have thought about the application, just not the impact on the db

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did work on a group of applications that were sharing the same database. We had a gem used by all the apps which included all the models.

This way we were able to ensure that all business logic in the same in all client apps (validations, scopes, etc).

There was a small overhead of switching between the apps to make changes and then making sure all other apps were up to date (especially if the change had bigger impact) but it did the job.

Comment: how about the migration files? Did you only include in one of the apps to avoid multiple migrations?

Comment: I think migration files where kept in the gem as well and then you could run migrations from any app that used the gem. But I don't remember exactly to be honest and don't have access to the code anymore